# regex with variable length

Tags: regex, bash

In Bash, can we match varying length of strings?
Eg.,

```
regex="FOO[0-9]{5}"
if [[ $1 =~ ${regex} ]]
```

will match FOO1111 or FOO98765 right...

But how do we match FOO1, FOO123 and FOO12345?
`regex="FOO[0-9]{1-5}"` doesnt work.

Is there a way do that in a simple manner or we just use:

```
regex5="FOO[0-9]{5}"
regex4="FOO[0-9]{4}"
regex3="FOO[0-9]{3}"
regex2="FOO[0-9]{2}"
regex="FOO[0-9]"
if [[ $1 =~ ${regex} || $1 =~ ${regex2} || $1 =~ ${regex3} || $1 =~ ${regex4} || $1 =~ ${regex5} ]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `{min,max}`:

```
regex="FOO[0-9]{1,5}"
```

And in fact you can use `^` and `$` for exact match:

```
[[ $v =~ ^${regex}$ ]]
```

#### Test

```
$ v=FOO
$ [[ $v =~ ^${regex}$ ]] && echo "yes"
$
$ v=FOO1
$ [[ $v =~ ^${regex}$ ]] && echo "yes"
yes
$ v=FOO123456
$ [[ $v =~ ^${regex}$ ]] && echo "yes"
$
```

Comment: I think, `FOO[0-9]{5}` is a shorthand for `FOO[0-9]{5,5}`. Right?

Comment: Exactly, @anishsane - I cannot find the reference now, but `{M,M}` is the same as `{M}`. Also, `{,M}` is the same as `{0,M}`.

Comment: @fedorqui, is FOO[0-9]{3,} valid?
and it means min 3 digits and max any no. of digits?

Comment: @VishnuKumar yes, that is a correct syntax: `regex="FOO[0-9]{5,}"` would get any number bigger or equal to `5`.